# Pulling local json data file through ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

```
var ColorHue = {
    pullColor: function(){
        var promise = $.Deferred();
        $.ajax ({
            url: 'ajax/color/Red.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'get',
            success: function(result){
                promise.resolve(result);
            }
        });
        return promise;
    } 
};

$('#colorHue').on('click', '#colorEnter', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nowColor = ColorHue.pullColor();
    nowColor.done(function(result){
        $('#colorDepot').append(result);
    });
});
```

I have this js file with a variable and method returning a promise object, which will be called upon a 'click' event.  So if the file is an html, I'm able to append it to the DOM without issue, but for some reason, this code throws an error when the file is json.  My json file is stored locally titled Red.json, and say the content is:

```
{
    'test': 'yes',
    'work': 'Maybe',
    'value': '0'
}
```

I was hoping the experts would be able to provide some insight.  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you running the file on local file system in which case you might be getting Access-Control-Allow-Origin error?

Comment: I think you need to replace the single quote with a double quote.

Comment: Either set async: false in your ajax request or put return command inside success block. Now, if it takes time for pulling json data when you return promise from pullColor, there won't be data in it.

Comment: @Gilsha: Never suggest `async: false` as an option! Work with asynchronous processes, not around them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

Red.json (double quotes)

```
{
    "test": "yes",
    "work": "Maybe",
    "value": "0"
}
```

js

```
var ColorHue = {
    pullColor: function(){
        // jquery ajax returns promise object
        return $.ajax ({
            url: 'ajax/color/Red.json',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'GET'
        });
    } 
};

$('#colorHue').on('click', '#colorEnter', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var nowColor = ColorHue.pullColor();
    // process jquery ajax promise object
    nowColor.done(function(result) {
        // append `result` keys and values to document
        $.each(result, function(k, v) {
            $('#colorDepot').append(k + ":" + v + "<br>");
        })
    });
});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/ds57f3xa/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.  The main issue was the lack of double quotes on the JSON data.  I really appreciate your and the communities' expertise, as I would have never considered that to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When the file is json, then for appending it to a div do something like
 $('#colorDepot').append(result.test);